# How To: Javascript make <img> go invisible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, invisible

I am trying to make blocks dissapear every 0.28 seconds. to make a puzzle guessing game.
I have made the time bar but i can't figure out how to let the  go invisible by using Javascript.

This is my HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="styles/game.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" title="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Title -->
    <title> Raad de foto </title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="../scripts/progressBar.js"></script>

    <?php
        $score = 0;
        $level = 1;         //Start level = 1
        $maxLevels = 5;
        $buttonColors = array("#1F5C99", "yellow", "red", "green");
        $buttonName = array("Wesley Sneijder", "Ron Vlaar", "Patrick van Aanholt", "Robin van Persie");
    ?>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="background">
        <div id="image">
            <!-- Top bar with text -->
            <div id="headerbar">
                <p class="left"> Raad De Speler </p>
                <p class="middle"> <?php echo $level ?> / <?php echo $maxLevels ?> </p>
                <p class="right"> Score : <?php echo $score ?></p>
            </div>
            <!-- img word afhankelijk van het "level" dat je bent -->
            <img src="../images/<?php echo $level ?>.jpg"></img>    <!-- <img src="../images/<?php echo $level; ?>.jpg"></img> -->
            <div id="blocks">
                <!-- Draw the blocks with logo? -->
                <?php
                $i=0;
                while ($i<36){
                ?>
                    <img id="<?php echo $i ?>" class="image" src="../images/block.jpg"></img>
                <?php $i=$i+1; } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">
                <div class="timebar" >
                    <div id="timebar" ></div>
                </div>
            <div id="votebuttons">
                <!-- Set the buttons -->
                <?php
                $i=0;
                while ($i<4){
                ?>
                    <input style="background-color: <?php echo $buttonColors[$i]; ?>" type="submit" value="<?php echo $buttonName[$i]; ?>">
                <?php $i=$i+1; } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="../scripts/progressBar2.js"></script>

</body>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Simply dumping the all of your code will only make it harder to find the issue. Please post only the relevant code, where you want to hide the images...

Comment: `document.getElementById("1").style.visibility = "hidden"; `

Comment: It is not a good practice to put a number as id of an element.

Comment: @LeoTAbraham Not _just_ a number anyway. `Square1` ... `Squaren` is perfectly acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById(<id>).style["visibility"] = "hidden"` should do.

Comment: Use `.style.visibility` instead of `.style["visibility"]`